# Как при переборе элементов убрать определённый элемент

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

```
set = [2, 4, 1, 0, 3];

function equality(set, e) {
    for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        if(e == set[i] ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function foring(set) {
    for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        if(equality(set, set[i]) == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

foring(set);
```

Надо найти одинаковые элементы в массиве. Если просто их обычно перебирать, мы можем столкнуться с тем же элементом который сравниваем с другими, поэтому `foring` в любом случае будет равен ИСТИНА.*

Можно ли при проверки из `set` исключить `e`. Может какие-то методы, функции?

.* поставим под `e` значение 3. При переборе мы наткнёмся на ту же 3 (set[4]). Но мы не хотим сравнивать с одно и то же между собой - надо сравнивать с остальными эл-нтами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function hasDuplicates(set) {
  for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
    if (existsInTail(set, i)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

  function existsInTail(set, index) {
    for (var i = index + 1; i < set.length; i++) {
      if (set[index] == set[i]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

var set = [2, 4, 1, 0, 3];
console.log(hasDuplicates(set));
```

Comment: с меня шоколадка)